# Need understanding as to why string.StartsWith() is true when it should be false

Tags: c#, string, .net-5

So I have this file that I download via ftp. The file is just a config file for a system at my company I work for.
Once the file is downloaded I open the file and processor the file.
Part of the processing of the file is to check to see if a line starts with a Unicode character `\u001a`.

This is where I am stumped because `.StartsWith("\u001a")` is always `true`, yet I cannot see why. If I view the file in Notepad++ or in a hex editor, I just don't see that.

So there is something I am missing here.

Here's a minimal example ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gn9z6t)):

```
// prints True in .NET 5
Console.WriteLine("Hello".StartsWith("\u001a"));
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237509/discussion-on-question-by-gaz83-need-understanding-as-to-why-string-startswith).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because a [breaking change in the globalizations APIs in .NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/string-comparison-net-5-plus). You can choose one of the following approaches

1. Use `StringComparison.Ordinal` or `OrdinalIgnoreCase`
2. Use NLS instead of ICU, [with one of the following ways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu#use-nls-instead-of-icu):

- In the project file:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.Globalization.UseNls" Value="true" />
</ItemGroup>
```

- In the runtimeconfig.json file:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
     "configProperties": {
       "System.Globalization.UseNls": true
      }
  }
}
```

- By setting the environment variable `DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_USENLS` to the value `true` or `1`.