# Weird String.StartsWith and .Contains behaviour after upgrade from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-6.0, .net-4.8

We are currently updating an application from .Net Framework 4.8 to .NET 6 and there is one particular thing that has me puzzled:

```cs
"MyString".StartsWith("\x01");
```

In .Net Framework this would return false. As I would expect, as the strings first character is not `'\x01'`

But in .Net 6 (also with .Net 5 already) this evaluates to true? We couldn't find any explanation on why this behaviour has changed, do you know any resource we could refer to?

We figured out, this can be solved by using the *new* overload of `StartsWith(char)` instead of the (old?) one with the string parameter.

The upgrade path did not replace those automatically, so I would expect the behaviour would be the same as well.

Comment: .NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6, not .NET Framework 4.8+1.2. The change happened to ensure .NET Core follows the Unicode standard behavior in all platforms

Comment: [.NET globalization and ICU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Need understanding as to why string.StartsWith() is true when it should be false](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69314093/3744182), agree?

Comment: In fact I found [22 C# answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=[c%23]%20NLS%20ICU%20%20is%3aa%20created%3a20120-11..&searchOn=3) containing ICU and NLS since Nov 2020, of which are for questions about why string searching and sorting are suddenly broken, so you're not the only one thrown for a loop by this.

Comment: @panagiotis-kanavos actually .NET 6 is .NET 6. They don't call it Core anymore.

Comment: @CalvinFurano actually it's not, no matter what the marketing name change was. Because that was nothing more than a marketing change, because a lot of companies were reluctant to move to a completely different platform. I remember when and why the name changed and how developers complained about the confusion that was sure to follow. The confusion that caused this question and a lot more similar questions. Like people asking why their WebForms projects failed, or why calls in their old WinForms projects failed despite the supposed "merging" of the platforms

Comment: @dbc such questions are perfectly understandable because people don't know they've moved to a completely different platform. Most Windows developers won't even know what ICU is. Especially since most people are moving to .NET Core [2 years after the change was actually made](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/globalization/5.0/icu-globalization-api)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because .NET changed from using NLS to ICU, and, performs culture aware comparisons by default for `StartsWith(string)`. There is some background on the changes in the [.NET runtime repository](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/77050).

Consider using ordinal comparisons:

```
"MyString".StartsWith("\x01", StringComparison.Ordinal);
```

Which will do what you expect.

Comment: Culture-aware was the default in .NET Framework too. The difference is that, as the link explains, in the Unicode standard some characters should be ignored. I wonder how many WT? moments occurred on Linux deployments before this change ....